# Is it possible to create a wineprefix from the command line (silently, unattended)

Tags: wine

I usually create wineprefixes with `WINEPREFIX=<path> winecfg`. But this always opens the gui program winecfg. Is there some way to create a wineprefix silenty, unattended, in a script?

Comment: Didn't you mean `WINEPREFIX=<path> wine winecfg`? See [Wineprefixes FAQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Wineprefixes).

Comment: As for as I can tell both ways of writing it does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the *WINEPREFIX* doesn't exist, it's created at the first execution of a *wine* command.

If you don't need any optional feature (like downloading mono or the browser), you can simply run a non-graphical command under *wine* with the *DISPLAY* variable unset, which will prevent `winecfg` to run successfully and appear. You can also ask it to not display any debug message by setting `WINEDEBUG=-all`.

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/my/test
$ unset DISPLAY
$ export WINEDEBUG=-all
$ WINEPREFIX=/tmp/my/test/wineprefix wine hostname
wine: created the configuration directory '/tmp/my/test/wineprefix'
wine: configuration in L"/tmp/my/test/wineprefix" has been updated.
SOMEHOST
```

Of course the intended usage above is from a script.